# Compare date to current month year

Tags: angularjs

In one of the API I am using I have a date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`
I am trying compare this date to just the current month and year. How do I just take out the month and year from that date and compare it in AngularJS?
I read the AngularJS Documentation for date formats and I can't seem just get the month and year from that format so that I can compare it with the current month and year

Comment: Try https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @KaustubhKhare read about it. Tried to use it. Still can't figure out. Saw a question on stack overflow as well on how to use moment.js But cant seem to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [momentjs docs.](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

- Docs to [parse date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
- Docs to [get from date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/)

Refer below code snippet,

```js
var apidate = moment('2019-01-01 11:31:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'); // API date

console.log("Day="+apidate.date()+ " Year="+apidate.year());

var now = moment(); // current date

console.log("Day="+now.date()+ " Year="+now.year());

// compare day and year of both dates
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com)

Convert the response from your API with eg;

```
responseDate = moment(responseAPI).format('YYYYMM')
```

You can then you can compare it with an existing date eg;

```
if (responseDate != moment(existingDate).format('YYYYMM')) { }
```